# How to set a view over a child view controller's view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am wondering if it is possible to set a view controller's view over one of its child view controller's view ?

Let's explain that with an example :

Let's say I have two `UIViewController`s : `parentVC`and `childVC`. `childVC` is a child of `parentVC`.
Now, I have a `UIButton` ( called `button` ) which is a subview of `parentVC.view`.

I set `childVC` from `parentVC` like that :

```
self.addChildViewController(childVC)
childVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
childVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height
self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
```

Now, I want `button` to show up even if `childVC.view` covers `parentVC.view`.

Do you guys think there's a way to do that ? I tried to play with `button.layer.zPosition` but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: try self.view.sendSubviewToBack(childVC.view)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, you just need to add the button to the view hierarchy or move the button up in the hierarchy after you add the child view controller.

Comment: Thanks Danny, kind of stupid from me not to have tried that before...
I finally just brought `button` to front : `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(button)`

Comment: how it will work, if button is not subView of childViewController..@randy & @ Danny

Comment: @Rohit: The child view controller's view lives inside the view hierarchy of the parent view controller. Think of it as a container that you can adapt in the same way you would any other view.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that first of all when you load a childview on a viewcontroller make a view like. There is a container on top covering almost 90% screen and at bottom there is a button,So when you load the view on container and sub view show's you on top if you tap a button then add a subview and bring that subview to front.